# Referencing a function within .map method

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm learning map functions (I'm very new to JS and coding).
First, I defined the inner function of the map-method directly where it is used; that works fine.
I tried to make it work via a reference to a function later, but I keep getting *"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"*.
Would appreciate any help as it is probably something very fundamental that I can't get my head around...

```js
// this is working 


let arrayOfWords = (['abc', 'bbc', 'cbc'])

function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
    let wordArray2 = arrayOfWords.map(function(item) {
     return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
  });
  return wordArray2
}

// "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

let arrayOfWords = (['abc', 'bbc', 'cbc'])

function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
  let wordArray2 = arrayOfWords.map(convert());
  return wordArray2
}

function convert(item){
     return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
  }
```

Comment: Please may you share an example of `arrayOfWords` which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `wordArray` in second function should be `arrayOfWords`?

Comment: `wordArray.map(convert())` should be `wordArray.map(convert)` (pass in a reference to the function, not the result of calling the function) but without seeing your input values we can't really help. In that first example, btw, you're not returning a value from the function.

Comment: of course, should be arrayOfWords, was an error when i rephrased for here

Comment: example on input: (['abc', 'bbc', 'cbc'])

Comment: Thanks Andy, that did the trick!

Comment: Will keep in mind to provide input values!

Comment: Welcome to the confusing world of JavaScript coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside map callback it has to be `convert` instead of `convert()`

```js
function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
  let wordArray2 = arrayOfWords.map(convert);
  return wordArray2
}

function convert(item) {
  return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
}

console.log(getUpperCase(['erferf', 'erferf', 'sdxsdxsdx']))
```

It is because `convert()` will immediately execute and `item` is `undefined`. So it will throw the error

```js
function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
  let wordArray2 = arrayOfWords.map(convert());
  return wordArray2
}

function convert(item) {
  console.log(item)
  return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
}
console.log(getUpperCase(['erferf', 'erferf', 'sdxsdxsdx']))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great to get help that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are *almost* correct except in the first one you're not *returning* anything from the function, and in the second you're *calling* the function and expecting results rather than passing a *reference* for the function to be used as a callback in the `map` function.

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'bbc', 'cbc'];

function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
  return arrayOfWords.map(function(item) {
     return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
  });
}

console.log(getUpperCase(arr));
```

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'bbc', 'cbc'];

function convert(item){
  return item = (item[0].toUpperCase()) + item.slice(1);
}


function getUpperCase(arrayOfWords) {
  return arrayOfWords.map(convert);
}

console.log(getUpperCase(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought, it is a function so it needs brackets; but your explanation cleared it up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parentheses in the callback function `convert`:

```
let wordArray2 = arrayOfWords.map(convert);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem exactly. Couldn't think that a reference should be without parentheses; makes sense now!